# IBM Bluemix user defined variables

Tags: python, ibm-cloud

How can we access `USER-DEFINED` variables in IBM Bluemix in Python? I have made a token in IBM Bluemix, but I am unable to access it from my Python script.

In the bluemix UI,

`token = <actual value of token>`

Comment: Can you please share the code you tried?

Comment: os.getenv('token') @AlexdaSilva , because USER_DEFINED is not a keyword in bluemix like VCAP_APPLICATION

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

`os.getenv('name of the key')`

where `name of the key` is key defined in Bluemix UI.